# Who is the woman who talks to young Tooru Amuro/Rei Furuya?

Tags: detective-conan

Tooru Amuro or Rey Furuya is the Black Organization member nicknamed Bourbon. He actually something like secret police agent (I can't remember the organization's name) who is working undercover in BO.
He as Tooru Amuro works at Poirot Cafe, and become Kogoro's apprentice.

I remember a case when Amuro, Conan, Ran and Kogoro are at the hospital and there's a case where a posion is used in a tea.

After Amuro and Conan realise who the suspect of the cases is, there's a kid with her mother counting the lift that coming from the upper floors.
When the kid counts to zero (they are on the ground floor), Amuro hears that and he seems surprised about it.
He also has a flashback to when he was a kid and was called "zero" by a woman.

So, who is she? Who's the woman who speaks to with young Amuro? What is their relation? And also why he called "zero" by this woman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about episode 771 of the anime (chapter 892 in the manga) The woman was Elena Miyano, the mother of  Shiho Miyano (Ai Haibara) who created the first prototipes of the APTX-4869 for the BO.

Acording to [DC world wiki](http://www.detectiveconanworld.com/wiki/Elena_Miyano#Rei_Furuya):

> While the true relationship between them has not been revealed yet, We know that they knew each other when Rei was younger. Rei got into many fights and it seems that Elena would bandage him up after the fights. However, one day, Elena had to move and could no longer bandage

Amuro's real name is Rei Furuya and "Rei” (零) means “zero” and that is possibly the reason why he is called zero.